# Angular routes are not working with Apache (404 Page Not Found)

Tags: angularjs, apache

I'm sure this is a duplicate question because I have been searching but I have literally tried every sample of code and cannot get this to work.

I have an angular site running on Apache with the following file structure

```
app
|_ _assets
   |_ css
   |_ img
   |_ js
   index.html (index being in the app folder)
```

I have 2 routes set up for /privacyPolicy and /terms and they are working locally fine but when I put them up on the server I just keep getting 404 errors saying that the pages don't exist.

What do I need to do to get this to go to index.html properly?

I have tried many different rewrite rules (like posted below) and the closest I have gotten to puts everything from index.html into app.js (no idea where that comes from).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

If anyone has any advice I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It's a good practice to put index.html in root folder. Such errors can be avoided by doing so

Comment: You mean not in the app folder but alongside?

Comment: Exactly. That's what the best practices say. @BrandonShega

Comment: Okay maybe I'll try that, thanks.